# What 's the cleaner way to declare a list of error codes in java spring

Tags: java, spring

Using Spring core 3.2 I'm coding a soap webservice. In this webservice I have to return an xml with an error code and an error label depending on my entries (correct or not).

Error code are int: 0, 1, 2, 99

What is the best way to define the error code :

- a class `ReturnCode` with constants
- an enum
- defining all the error code directly in the class where I've defined my validation method like :

  `private static final String CODE_ERREUR8 = "8";`

anything else?

Comment: This code convention you want to use, is service specific or it will be used on multiple services? If it's the latter, I'd skip with your 3rd choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use enum, with constructor that takes the code value, and some info about it and store it, then this enum should have an access methods to this fields.

It give you the possibility to store some human-readable info about the error, or some other relevant informations that you could need, where the CONSTANTS can't do that.

Storing it class it is not good practice, since other parts of your program could need to use those codes, so to which class should they belong? It is also easy to find an Enum, while in class you could have a lot of this CONSTANTS and then this would make confusion for what they are.

Making a special class for that was the way, when java have not enums yet :)